# Create user session from oauth access token for a facebook user

Tags: facebook

In my application I have collected the access token with offline access to facebook from the users.

I would like to open a facebook user session with this access token if the user logs in to my application so that the user does not have to login to facebook.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your application is built, so it's hard to give a concise answer.
One way would be to store the access token and user id with the user details in the user database. When the user logs in, you can look to see if these value exists.

If they do exist, you can create a call with something like:

http://graph.facebook.com/**$userID**/friends?access_token=**$userAccessToken**